# How to access AngularJS project installed on remote server?

Tags: node.js, angular, port, angular-cli

I created a project using Angular CLI on a remote server (CentOS). When I compiled the project I used the option ng serve --host 123.456.789.10 (my server ip) and got a message the project can be listen on http://123.456.789.10:4200
However I can't see the Angular welcome page as expected at this point and get the message "Problems loading the page". Server support says ports are opened by default.
Am I missing other settings when compiling the project?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out and I had to compile again using

```
ng serve --host host-ip-address --public-host http://host-ip-address(had to add http://)
```

It's a known issue discussed in this thread:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6349